# Custom $_Get variable to clean url in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, clean-url

I am currently working on wordpress. URL 0f site is something like this

> **example.com/dashboard-form/?din=random12**.

I want the url to be like this

> **example.com/dashboard-form/random**.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Active rewrite engine and there is probably a module who able you to rewrite url

Comment: You can do this with url rewrites build in to wordpress http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/wordpress-url-rewrite/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be added on init:

To register your custom variable ('din' in the question)

```
add_rewrite_tag('%mycustomvar%','([^&]+)');
```

To create a re-write rule:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^product/([0-9]{1,})/?','index.php?p=4&mycustomvar=$matches[1]','top')
```

For more please refer below link:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48487/how-to-retrieve-get-variables-from-rewritten-urls

Try to add rewrite rule and let me know if any query.